# Multiple expire options for one cookie? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, cookies

I was wondering if there is a way to set multiple expire options for one cookie.  For example, I want a cookie to expire when the user closes their browser and in 30 minutes.

Is this possible?

> YAHOO.util.Cookie.setSubs("cookiename", cookieData, { expires: 0, expires: time() - 1800, path: "/", domain: "cbc.ca" });

Answer (score 3):

From the RFC:

> If an attribute appears more than once in a
>      cookie, the behavior is undefined.

There's no way to set up a cookie to expire like that; at least, there's no cross-browser way to do it. (Also, as far as I know the appropriate attribute is "Max-Age", not "expires"; maybe that name is part of the YUI api however.)

Expiring a session after a period of time is generally something that secure server-side code does on its own, and explicitly. (In other words, the session cookie is explicitly rejected as invalid if its timestamp indicates excessive age.)

Comment: @say2joe according to [RFC 2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt), it's "Max-Age". Netscape supported "Expires" before the RFC, but that was before 1997 :-)

Comment: That's for the HTTP header description ... not the JavaScript string to set a cookie. If you're manipulating the Cookie via a server-side HTTP Header response, then the RFC's description would be correct. This question is pertinent to JavaScript not server-side code, however.

Comment: Ah OK I see what you mean. Yes you're right; I was stuck thinking about the machinery behind it. You can, however, set "max-age" as part of the JavaScript cookie-setting string in non-IE browsers (and maybe IE9+).

Answer (score 2):

You can have the cookie set the onload event, but you can not have two expire times. You can get the time the page unloads and then set the cookie for +30 minutes. But you Cant have the cookie set when the browser closes, you would need a plugin to do that, but when the page closes you can.